# Beastly table taking too long to run despite small results set returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a beast of a table which is in the outer query having more than 40million rows. I am doing an incremental/delta load picking up data for only 6 days but this query for some odd reason is taking more than 25min, despite the fact that its only bringing in 6 days worth of data. The query is as follows:

```
        SELECT
        ActivityId,
        ActivityPartyId,
        ISNULL(AddressUsed,'*Unknown*') As AddressUsed,
        isnull(Cast(IsPartyDeleted As INT),-9) As IsPartyDeleted,
        Isnull(ParticipationTypeMask,-9) as ParticipationTypeMask,
        PartyId,
        ISNULL(PartyIdName,'*Unknown*') As PartyIdName,
        Isnull(PartyObjectTypeCode,0) as PartyObjectTypeCode
        from ActivityPartyBase


        INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT activityid AS apid
        from ActivityPointerBase

        WHERE
        CreatedOn BETWEEN   DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,2,getdate()), 0) AND  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,getdate()), 0)

         or

        ModifiedOn BETWEEN   DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,6,getdate()), 0) AND  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,getdate()), 0)


        ) sub
        ON   ActivityId = sub.apid
```

The Result the subquery is bringing back is only 80,000 rows which is rather small compare to do an inner join to bring back from the outer table.

I was wondering if there is a way to improve the performance of this query at all or create an index in one of the columns. The activityPointerBase table has an clustered index on the activityId but the ActivityParty Table has a clustered index on the ActivityPartyId which are different columns.

Can anyone please advise the best way to improve this query and run time.

Comment: Assuming the `CreatedOn` and `ModifiedOn` criteria limits a lot of your data, it might be beneficial to change your query to be 2 queries with union + index those fields.

Comment: Just checking, but, are either of those views instead of tables?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 0):

Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

If these are base tables and not views, you should check existing indexes and test to see if you would benefit from adding any of these indexes:

```
create nonclustered index ix_ActivityPointerBase_CreatedOn_inc_ActivityId
  on dbo.ActivityPointerBase(CreatedOn)
    include (ActivityId);

create nonclustered index ix_ActivityPointerBase_ModifiedOn_inc_ActivityId
  on dbo.ActivityPointerBase(ModifiedOn)
    include (ActivityId);

create nonclustered index ix_ActivityPartyBase_ActivityId_Cover
  on dbo.ActivityPartyBase(ActivityId)
    include (
        ActivityPartyId
      , AddressUsed
      , IsPartyDeleted
      , ParticipationTypeMask
      , PartyId
      , PartyIdName
      , PartyObjectTypeCode
     );
```

If ModifiedOn is not nullable and equals CreatedOn when it is created, then you can skip that part of your `where` clause.

```
select 
    ActivityId
  , ActivityPartyId
  , isnull(AddressUsed, '*Unknown*') as AddressUsed
  , isnull(cast(IsPartyDeleted as int), - 9) as IsPartyDeleted
  , isnull(ParticipationTypeMask, - 9) as ParticipationTypeMask
  , PartyId
  , isnull(PartyIdName, '*Unknown*') as PartyIdName
  , isnull(PartyObjectTypeCode, 0) as PartyObjectTypeCode
from ActivityPartyBase
inner join (
   select activityid as apid
   from ActivityPointerBase
   where 
       --CreatedOn between dateaday(day, datediff(day, 2, getdate()), 0) and dateaday(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) 
   --or 
   ModifiedOn between dateaday(day, datediff(day, 6, getdate()), 0) and dateaday(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
  ) sub
    on ActivityId = sub.apid
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no shame in #Temp Tables, especially when you can take advantage of stats and indexes.

```
SELECT activityid AS apid
 INTO  #TempID
 FROM  ActivityPointerBase
 WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN   DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,2,getdate()), 0) AND  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,getdate()), 0)
    or ModifiedOn BETWEEN  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,6,getdate()), 0) AND  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,getdate()), 0)
 ORDER BY activityid

Create Index idx on #TempID (apid)


SELECT ActivityId,
       ActivityPartyId,
       ISNULL(AddressUsed,'*Unknown*') As AddressUsed,
       isnull(Cast(IsPartyDeleted As INT),-9) As IsPartyDeleted,
       Isnull(ParticipationTypeMask,-9) as ParticipationTypeMask,
       PartyId,
       ISNULL(PartyIdName,'*Unknown*') As PartyIdName,
       Isnull(PartyObjectTypeCode,0) as PartyObjectTypeCode
FROM   ActivityPartyBase A
JOIN   #TempID B on A.ActivityId = B.apid
```